# How to keep last JQuery DIV position after refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

example http://maps.lt 
when you zoom in some city, u click refresh and then page automaticaly starts from begining, 
The point is that  we want after refresh, keep same position zoomed in.
thank you.

Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day; show him how to catch fish, and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: How to catch a fish: look at how other people are catching fish an mimic them.

Comment: nice answer, whatever.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the localStorage API.
`localStorage.set("key", "value");`

You can use the set method every time the user moves, and then when they reload the page, you can do
`localStorage.get("key");`

, which will return the value for that key.   This can also be expanded with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` for stringifying and parsing JSON, which can be stored and retrieved from `localStorage`.

You can also use `parseInt(localStorage.get("key"));` to retrieve a number.


Hope I helped!